# Gradle: Cannot Access BasicNameValuePair

Tags: java, android, gradle, websocket, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio for app development. I followed a tutorial recently in what I built a app that should connect to a server and should send messages. The problem is I cannot compile the app in Android Studio. I even tried the provided source code from the tutorial. Tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-2/
MainActivity.java:

```
package nl.doho.webgroupchat;

import nl.doho.webgroupchat.other.Message;
import nl.doho.webgroupchat.other.Utils;
import nl.doho.webgroupchat.other.WsConfig;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.codebutler.android_websockets.WebSocketClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// LogCat tag
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Button btnSend;
private EditText inputMsg;

private WebSocketClient client;

// Chat messages list adapter
private MessagesListAdapter adapter;
private List<Message> listMessages;
private ListView listViewMessages;

private Utils utils;

// Client name
private String name = null;

// JSON flags to identify the kind of JSON response
private static final String TAG_SELF = "self", TAG_NEW = "new",
        TAG_MESSAGE = "message", TAG_EXIT = "exit";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    inputMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMsg);
    listViewMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_messages);

    utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());

    // Getting the person name from previous screen
    Intent i = getIntent();
    name = i.getStringExtra("name");

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Sending message to web socket server
            sendMessageToServer(utils.getSendMessageJSON(inputMsg.getText()
                    .toString()));

            // Clearing the input filed once message was sent
            inputMsg.setText("");
        }
    });

    listMessages = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new MessagesListAdapter(this, listMessages);
    listViewMessages.setAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * Creating web socket client. This will have callback methods
     * */
    client = new WebSocketClient(URI.create(WsConfig.URL_WEBSOCKET + URLEncoder.encode(name)), new WebSocketClient.Listener() {


        @Override
        public void onConnect() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Got string message! %s", s));

            parseMessage(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(byte[] bytes) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Got binary message! %s", bytesToHex(bytes)));

            parseMessage(bytesToHex(bytes));
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnect(int i, String s) {
            String message = String.format(Locale.US, "Disconnected! Code: %d Reason: %s", i, s);

            showToast(message);

            utils.storeSessionId(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR! : " + e);

            showToast("ERROR! : " + e);
        }
    }, null);

    client.connect();
}

/**
 * Method to send message to web socket server
 * */
private void sendMessageToServer(String message) {
    if (client != null && client.isConnected()) {
        client.send(message);
    }
}

/**
 * Parsing the JSON message received from server The intent of message will
 * be identified by JSON node 'flag'. flag = self, message belongs to the
 * person. flag = new, a new person joined the conversation. flag = message,
 * a new message received from server. flag = exit, somebody left the
 * conversation.
 * */
private void parseMessage(final String msg) {

    try {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(msg);

        // JSON node 'flag'
        String flag = jObj.getString("flag");

        // if flag is 'self', this JSON contains session id
        if (flag.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_SELF)) {

            String sessionId = jObj.getString("sessionId");

            // Save the session id in shared preferences
            utils.storeSessionId(sessionId);

            Log.e(TAG, "Your session id: " + utils.getSessionId());

        } else if (flag.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_NEW)) {
            // If the flag is 'new', new person joined the room
            String name = jObj.getString("name");
            String message = jObj.getString("message");

            // number of people online
            String onlineCount = jObj.getString("onlineCount");

            showToast(name + message + ". Currently " + onlineCount
                    + " people online!");

        } else if (flag.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_MESSAGE)) {
            // if the flag is 'message', new message received
            String fromName = name;
            String message = jObj.getString("message");
            String sessionId = jObj.getString("sessionId");
            boolean isSelf = true;

            // Checking if the message was sent by you
            if (!sessionId.equals(utils.getSessionId())) {
                fromName = jObj.getString("name");
                isSelf = false;
            }

            Message m = new Message(fromName, message, isSelf);

            // Appending the message to chat list
            appendMessage(m);

        } else if (flag.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_EXIT)) {
            // If the flag is 'exit', somebody left the conversation
            String name = jObj.getString("name");
            String message = jObj.getString("message");

            showToast(name + message);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if(client != null && client.isConnected()){
        client.disconnect();
    }
}

/**
 * Appending message to list view
 * */
private void appendMessage(final Message m) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            listMessages.add(m);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // Playing device's notification
            playBeep();
        }
    });
}

private void showToast(final String message) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Plays device's default notification sound
 * */
public void playBeep() {

    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),
                notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
    }

}
```

Websocket library: https://github.com/koush/android-websockets
Gradle Error:

```
      D:\Users\Douwe\AndroidStudioProjects\WebMobileGroupChat\app\src\main\java\nl\doho\webgroupchat\MainActivity.java:94: error: cannot access BasicNameValuePair
        client = new WebSocketClient(URI.create(WsConfig.URL_WEBSOCKET +     URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8")), new WebSocketClient.Listener() {
                 ^
  class file for BasicNameValuePair not found
1 error

 FAILED

  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
 Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Unfortunately I didn't manage to get this in a code block

Comment: remove and add library to compilation unit

Comment: Can you please be al little more specific